# Running multiple linear regression in R

Tags: r, linear-regression

How would one run a multiple linear regression on R, with > 100 covariates?

Is there a faster way besides `(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + ... + x100)`?

Comment: Check the formula `y ~ .`

Comment: If you want to choose specific columns, you can also use some other options for construction of model formulas. For example: `lm(reformulate(paste0("x", c(1,24:28, 63:66, 98)), "y"), data=dat)`.

Comment: Please change the title to 'multiple linear regression', which is what you are referring too.

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2358/explain-the-difference-between-multiple-regression-and-multivariate-regression

Answer (score 0):

```
lm(y ~ ., data = YourData)
```

You can use the `.` , which takes all columns other than the response column from the supplied data as covariates.